# How does $P(A \cap D')$ = $P(A) - P(A \cap D)$

Tags: probability

In a book I'm reading it has an example in the probability section, the example aside it provides these probabilities:

$$P(A) = .82$$
$$P(D) = .83$$
$$P(D \cap A) = .78$$

Then it asks to compute $P(A|D)$ and $P(D|A)$ which I understood, and then it showed:

$$P(A|D') = {P(A \cap D')\over P(D')} = {{.82 - .78}\over .17}$$

I understand how $P(D')$ is computed, but I don't understand how from what it seems like above:

$$P(A \cap D') = P(A) - P(A \cap D)$$

intuitively it seems like the above calculation would give $P(A' \cap D)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that $A=(A\cap D)\cup (A\cap D')$ and these two sets are disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Since $D\sqcup D^{\prime}=\Omega$, it follows that
$$ A=A\cap\Omega=A\cap(D\sqcup D^{\prime})=(A\cap D)\sqcup(A\cap D^{\prime})$$
Therefore
$$ \mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap D)+\mathbb{P}(A\cap D^{\prime})$$
or
$$ \mathbb{P}(A\cap D^{\prime})=\mathbb{P}(A)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap D)$$

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is the disjoint union of $A \cap D$ and $A \cap D'$, so $P(A)=P(A\cap D)+P(A \cap D')$. Rearranging this gives the formula you posted.

Intuitively, if we want $P(A\cap D')$, then we want all the events in $A$, except those in $D$ (i.e., except those in $A \cap D$. Hence $P(A\cap D')=P(A)-P(A \cap D)$.